# Return map from shorthand anonymous function

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to return a map (or vector) like this, with the shorthand notation?

```
(#({:ok %}) "lol") => {:ok "lol"}  ;; this doesn't work
```

Functionally equivalent longhand example:

```
((fn [x] {:ok x}) "lol") => {:ok "lol"}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of alternatives

`(#(hash-map :ok %) :yoo)`

`(#(do {:ok %}) :yoo)`

Comment: `do` is nice. I was just looking for something short and sweet.